# How to add meta data to an invoice in Laravel Cashier?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

As stated in the [issues](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/issues/421) on Laravel Cashier. It does not state how to add meta data to invoices/charges.

```
Auth::user()->invoiceFor('Stickers', 500, ['metadata' => ['VAT' => 'TEST']]);
```

After following how to do this based off the issue, as seen above, it successfully creates the invoice however, the meta data is not added.

How can I add meta data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass meta data to the fourth parameter of `invoiceFor()`.
The third parameter is an array of options for the invoice item whereas the other one is also an array of options but for the invoice itself.

```php
$user->invoiceFor('Stickers', 500, [], [
    'tax_percent' => 20,
    'metadata' => [
        'custom-option' => 'value',
    ]
]);
```